# sed - delete all characters before dash

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have list of filenames for which I want to remove all character before the first instance of `-`. So the names below in the Before: list appears as those in the After: list.

```
Before:
Adam James - Welcome Home.txt
Mike & Harry - One Upon - A Time.txt
William-Kent - Prince & The Frog.txt

After:
Welcome Home.txt
One Upon - A Time.txt
Prince & The Frog.txt
```

I've been playing around with sed for hours with no avail.

I found that `sed 's/ - .*//'` removes all characters after the first instance of `-` but I cannot find the same for before.

Comment: anubhava's answer did the job ^^ Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="- "} NF>1{$1="";sub(/^- */, "")}'1 inFIle
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/2tBU4v

Comment: still won't work, you could test it locally first. e.g. the position of `1` ?

Comment: Hi anubhava, that's perfect. is it possible to edit so it also works on, i.e. Mike & Harry - One-Upon - A Time.txt => One-Upon - A Time.txt

Comment: did you compare the output in your Live Demo to the output in Question? :) ... OFS is missing

Comment: @scripting_newbie: Pls check the latest demo: http://ideone.com/2tBU4v that gives expected output for `Mike & Harry - One-Upon - A Time.txt => One-Upon - A Time.txt`

Comment: This also worked. Thank you. I must say there are some really smart people on this site. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @scripting_newbie and it is unusual, a sed/awk question could have so many answers.. your question is interesting indeed. looks easy, with corners...:D

Comment: Totally agree with @Kent for this interesting question. (+1 from me)

Comment: Agreed, It certainly made me think for a second @scripting_newbie did you test my `grep` solution?

Comment: @sudo_O: Must say that your grep was very kool answer too, esp. the use of `\K`

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,index($0," - ")+3)}' file
Welcome Home.txt
One Upon - A Time.txt
Prince & The Frog.txt
```

i.e. just print from the end of the first occurrence of " - " to the end of the line.

Answer (score 4):

Like this.

```
sed 's/^[^-]* - //'
```

Many regular expression engines allow `*?` for a non-greedy search, but sed doesn't.

EDIT: This won't change the William-Kent example, the embedded hyphen prevents a match.

(Also, Perl ships a very handy `rename` script to batch-rename files using regular expressions, but not every distribution installs it.)

Comment: I had this line too, but the last line in example `William-Kent...` won't work. :)

Comment: Did you try `ssed -R` - I believe that is a `sed` with non-greedy option.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest approach is too use `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po ' - \K.*' file
Welcome Home.txt
One Upon - A Time.txt
Prince & The Frog.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

In pure Bash (no extra child processes spawned):

```
list=('Adam James - Welcome Home.txt' 'Mike & Harry - One Upon - A Time.txt')
for str in "${list[@]}"; do echo ${str#*-}; done
```

Prints:

```
Welcome Home.txt
One Upon - A Time.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in plain POSIX sh, without bash features:

```
$ cat the_file_names 
Adam James - Welcome Home.txt
Mike & Harry - One Upon - A Time.txt
William-Kent - Prince & The Frog.txt

$ { while read FN; do echo ${FN#* - }; done; } < /tmp/the_file_names 
Welcome Home.txt
One Upon - A Time.txt
Prince & The Frog.txt

$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `gawk` may be easier for this job.

the usage of `FPAT` could simplify the problem:

```
awk -v FPAT="- .*$" 'sub(/^- /,"",$1)' file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "Adam James - Welcome Home.txt
Mike & Harry - One Upon - A Time.txt
William-Kent - Prince & The Frog.txt"|awk -v FPAT="- .*$" 'sub(/^- /,"",$1)'
Welcome Home.txt
One Upon - A Time.txt
Prince & The Frog.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed 's/ - /\n/;s/.*\n//' file
```