# wget:: How to rename all the already dowloaded files as name given by wget --content-dispostion?

Tags: linux, download, wget

I have downloaded 1200 jpeg files using `wget`. But the name of the files are based on links from which they are downloaded.

For ex.
`http://www.*.*.*/index.php?id=0MwfTcqbP9dl1_icR3_gVezE8tlpUJt-wumA5hHjpjk` will download the file with name **index.php?id=0MwfTcqbP9dl1_icR3_gVezE8tlpUJt-wumA5hHjpjk.jpg** but its name on server is different. Now I want all the files to be named as the name on the server.

One way is to delete all the files and re-download it with `wget` option `--content-dispostion` but total size of the download is 8GB and downloading it again is not a good option.

How can I rename all the downloaded files as names on server?

Edit: Name of the jpeg files downloaded from the links using  `wget --content-disposition` or browser would be like **2014:08:09_18:07:51_IMG_5543.jpg** (not created by `wget`, it's **oringinal name** on server, uploader's file name). I want all the files to be named as their **oringinal names** without again downloading them.

Comment: Just to be sure, you know about sed and regex? than you could rename all files and save some time

Comment: I know regex and I'll try to learn sed while implementing. But if you throw some light on how to retrieve the file names from the server without downloading the file, it will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe a misunderstanding, but I think you want to get rid of everything in the filenames before the "-" - then this could be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201134/sed-delete-all-characters-before-dash There is an answer with demo-link.

Comment: Yeah a bit misunderstanding, I have given a edit to my question, have a look. Original file name is completely different and it can't be told just by looking at the link.

Comment: If the webserver supports HEAD request, you can use commands like wget --server-response --spider $URL, otherwise you can use range 0-1 to get one byte only. After you have the response heahers, you can write a script to rename.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. Webserver supports HEAD request and It's done. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the webserver supports HEAD request, you can use commands like `wget --server-response --spider $URL`, otherwise you can use range 0-1 to get one byte only. After you have the response heahers, you can write a script to rename. –  Wu Yongzheng